# PHPUnit analyze expected method call parameter

Tags: phpunit

Is there any way I can test this method fully since I'm not passing model directly into it but am expecting my manager to create it for me?

```
public function giveAchievement(User $user, $achievementType)
{
    $a2p = new Achievement2User();
    $a2p->setUser($user);
    $a2p->setAchievement($this->em->getReference(AchievementManager::ACHIEVEMENT_CLASS, $achievementType));
    $a2p->setObtainedOn(new \DateTime());

    $this->em->persist($a2u);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Since I mocked `$em`, I can check if it's `persist` method is called with instance of `Achievement2User`:

```
$this->em->expects($this->once())
    ->method('persist')
    ->with($this->isInstanceOf('Achievement2User'));
```

But is there any way I can actually check if passed model has the `User` and `Achievement` fields set up correctly?

Comment: What class are you trying to test?

Comment: It doesn't matter, lets call it `AchievementManager` and it contains only one method, the one I wrote source code of. `User` and `Achievement2User` are just plain models with getters+setters and 0 logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to do it:

```
// Create $userObject and $achievementObject entities/models

$this->em->expects($this->once())
    ->method('persist')
    ->with($this->isInstanceOf('Achievement2User'))
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function (Achievement2User $a2u) use ($userObject, $achievementObject) {
        $this->assertTrue($a2u === $userObject);
        $this->assertTrue($a2u === $achievementObject);
    }));
```

PHPUnit will apparently pass expected methods parameters to callback function.